# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this:

`List<String> _filters = <String>[8, 11];`

I pass this `_filters` into this endpoint:

```
this.api.setInterests(token, _filters)
  .then((res) {
    print(res);
  });
```

which looks like this:

```
  Future setInterests(String token, List<String> interests) {
    return _netUtil.post(BASE_URL + "/setinterests", body: {
      "token": token,
      "interests": interests
    }).then((dynamic res) {
      return res;
    });
  }
```

Passing `_filters` always throws the error:

`type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

I don't know what else dart wants from me.

Comment: Check whether token is of type string too. Also try to define `_filters` with var instead of List<String> and remove <String>. That should be enough for most purposes in Dart.

Comment: Checked. `token` is a string. It comes from `final token = prefs.getString('token');`. Changing to `var` doesn't fix it. The thing is, the error message makes absolutely no sense, so debugging is vague to even begin with

Comment: Using var throws this back `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`.

Comment: Are you sure that `body` can take in `List`'s? It looks like it is trying to cast it to a `String` to me, which obviously does not work.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer. I just added `.toString()` to the `_filters` List.

```
  this.api.setInterests(token, _filters.toString())
  .then((res) {
    print(res);
  });
```

Comment: Good to hear that you solved your issue. I was just writing a comment as a friendly reminder. :) 
First of all, 
`List<String> _filters = <String>[8, 11];` this part is giving an error. 
This will give us a error below.
`
error: The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the list type 'String'.
`
I would fix the array the array issue too.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to add  `json.encode(data)` in body
2. Add these two header 
   'Content-type': 'application/json',
     'Accept': 'application/json',
3. Create map of your data

   ```
   final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['token'] = token;
    data['interests'] = interests;
   ```
4. Call api like this

   ```
   http.post(url,<br>
   body: json.encode(data),
   headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json',
     'Accept': 'application/json'},
   encoding: encoding)
   .then((http.Response response) {

        // print(response.toString());

   }
   ```