# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast. What is the Solution for this?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass data to node api from flutter code which contains list and string type of values but it gives me above error. What is the Solution for this?

Code I have written in Model Class is:

`

```
String? uid;
String? userName;
String? email;
List<String>? favDishes;
```

`

`

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
  return {`your text`
    "uid" : uid,
    "userName" : userName,
    "email" : email,
    "favDishes": favDishes
  };
}
```

`

Comment: add more code, we can't say anything based on this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for bad answering, you just need to refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849282/18588777

Answer (score 0):

Done...
The Problem was in my Api not in this class. My Api was only accepting string type so I added headers field and now it performs perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry for bad answering, you just need to refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849282/18588777